# How to capture test results from Karma?

Tags: karma-jasmine, workflow, github-actions

I'm trying to set up a GitHub action workflow where I run unit test cases and if it is successful, I will deploy my app.

[image: Result in Github action]

It prints the success or failed then continues to next step. When I tried to get the output from the test in GitHub action it returns an empty object.

What should I set up in my Karma config to get the output i.e SUCCESS or FAILED?

Comment: Hi @Udhaya, if you [edit] your question, you can include some of the configuration you have so far, this will bump the question to the top of the list so that it gets attention again and also help the Stack Overflow community answer the question. Hope this helps.